# SSH push to github fails, but can authenticate

Tags: git, powershell, ssh

For some reason I seem to be unable to `push` to github using **Powershell**, but using **CygWin** seem to be running smoothly.

I'm working on setting up automatic pushes to a repository using Task Scheduler, and it simply seems more efficient using **Powershell** for that.

What bothers me is that I'm perfectly able to ssh into my account using `ssh -T github@github.com` and the config file seems to be setup correctly too.
See bellow image:

[image]

From my basic understanding of Git, the error message I'm given when pushing simply says that I might not be correctly authenticated. But looking at my `ssh` I seem to be authenticated?

This is my config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:Somename/SomeRepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The Scheduled script:

```
echo "cool"

git add .

git commit -m "some stuff"

git push origin master
```

`ssh -vT git@github.com` output:

```
MVC master $ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Todai\\.ssh\\ps_id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi SomeName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2640, received 1992 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13538.5, received 10215.4
debug1: Exit status 1
```

`git config --list`:

```
MVC master $ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=todai88
user.email=joabaj88@gmail.com
credential.helper=manager
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:SomeName/PluralSight_MVC.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
user.name=SomeName
user.email=SomeEmail@email.com
```

Comment: The same sequence of commands works with `Command Prompt` also?
Another thing, why do you need to `ssh` first? You can simply `push` your code if the ssh-key has already been added to your repo.

Comment: The reason I'm using SSH first is to show that the agent seems to be authenticating normally...
About the `command prompt`, that seems to actually get `access denied`. No clue what that means in terms of my problem

Comment: Right. And, the `SSH key` has been added to your repo, right? And, you have `Git Bash`?

Comment: Yeah, the SSH key is added and have been used according to `Github`. `Git bash` is installed, but also seems to have issues when trying to push (same as `powershell`)

Comment: Okay. Did you enable the `Command Prompt` or `PowerShell` to use `Git` commands while installing `Git Bash`? Can you add your script that you are scheduling with `Task Scheduler`?

Comment: Yeah, git commands work fine on both of them. Edited with the script. It's really basic; mainly just to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Well, everything looks fine -- `SSH key`, `Git Bash`, etc. Can you run `ssh -vT git@github.com` and add its output along with your question? Maybe, there'll be more info for debugging this in `verbose` mode.

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: Also did some `ssh-add` in `Git Bash`, and that seems to work now, but not `Powershell`

Comment: Did you check it with `Admin` privileges?

Comment: Yeah. In all of the programs...

Comment: Do you see your `Git` global configurations e.g. `user.name`, `user.email`, etc. in `PowerShell`?

Comment: Added the config. All seems fine

Comment: Well, it is strange. I'll try to reproduce it and update here later.

Comment: Cheers, man. I really would want this to be fixed ASAP, but honestly can't find any good info about my problem... :/

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I have a few different SSH-keys on my account, two of which are available (in my .ssh/ folder) on windows. One for CygWin and one for PowerShell. I'm not sure if that matters, especially considering I can authenticate on Powershell, but simply can't push.

Comment: Have you carefully checked that the SSH key being used in your SSH test is the same exact SSH key that has permission on _this_ repo? All the SSH test actually proves is that using your C:\\Users\\Todai\\.ssh\\ps_id_rsa key, you have authenticated to _some_ Github account, it does not necessarily mean that you have authenticated to a Github account that has permission on _this_ repository...

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine. I mean, how could I test this? I know for a fact that the ssh's associated github account is the owner of the repository that I'm pushing to. Especially considering I can push with *CygWin* (though that's on a different ssh-key).